# Can't use unix socket in torrc with nginx (Onion Service)

Tags: onion-services, server

Im using Ubuntu 22.04 and everytime I try to use a unix socket in torrc config file the onion service doesn't work

torrc config file:

```
Log notice file /var/log/tor/log
RunAsDaemon 1
SocksPort 0
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/gunicorn/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
HiddenServicePort 80 unix:/home/agua/sockets/nginx.sock
```

nginx site config file:

```
server { 
        #listen 80;
        listen unix:/home/agua/sockets/nginx.sock;      
        allow "unix:";
        server_name v3onionurlexample.onion
}
```

the nginx.sock has the following permissions:

```
namei -nom /home/agua/sockets/nginx.sock

f: /home/agua/sockets/nginx.sock
 drwxr-xr-x root root     /
 drwxr-xr-x root root     home
 drwxr-xr-x agua agua     agua
 drwxrwxrwx agua agua     sockets
 srwxrwxrwx agua www-data nginx.sock
```

If I use in torrc `HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80`
and in nginx site config file `listen 80;` the service works perfectly.

But https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup/ reccomends using unix sockets

Any help is well received im new in this

edit:

I have changed the permission to nginx.sock file to the following because im running tor daemon with `sudo systemctl start tor` this still doesn't work

```
namei -nom /home/agua/sockets/nginx.sock
f: /home/agua/sockets/nginx.sock
 drwxr-xr-x root       root     /
 drwxr-xr-x root       root     home
 drwxr-xr-x agua       agua     agua
 drwxrwxrwx agua       agua     sockets
 srwxrwxrwx debian-tor www-data nginx.sock
```

sock file can be read by any user or group so permissions shouldnt be the problem here

tor service status:

```
tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)

     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2022-06-24 02:13:41 CEST; 26s ago

    Process: 39734 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 39734 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

        CPU: 1ms



jun 24 02:13:41 agua-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
jun 24 02:13:41 agua-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopping Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
jun 24 02:13:41 agua-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
jun 24 02:13:41 agua-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Finished Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

edit 2:
systemctl status tor@default

```
tor@default.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP

     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor@default.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)

     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-06-24 18:03:26 CEST; 53s ago

    Process: 41403 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -Z -m 02755 -o debian-tor -g debian-tor -d /run/tor (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

    Process: 41404 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0 --verify-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

   Main PID: 41405 (tor)

      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1084)

     Memory: 49.6M

        CPU: 534ms

     CGroup: /system.slice/system-tor.slice/tor@default.service

             └─41405 /usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0



jun 24 18:03:26 agua-VirtualBox tor[41404]: Jun 24 18:03:26.548 [notice] Tor 0.4.6.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.0.2, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.3>

jun 24 18:03:26 agua-VirtualBox tor[41404]: Jun 24 18:03:26.548 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/

jun 24 18:03:26 agua-VirtualBox tor[41404]: Jun 24 18:03:26.549 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".

jun 24 18:03:26 agua-VirtualBox tor[41404]: Jun 24 18:03:26.550 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".

jun 24 18:03:26 agua-VirtualBox tor[41404]: Configuration was valid

jun 24 18:03:26 agua-VirtualBox tor[41405]: Jun 24 18:03:26.572 [notice] Tor 0.4.6.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.0.2, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.3>

jun 24 18:03:26 agua-VirtualBox tor[41405]: Jun 24 18:03:26.572 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/

jun 24 18:03:26 agua-VirtualBox tor[41405]: Jun 24 18:03:26.572 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".

jun 24 18:03:26 agua-VirtualBox tor[41405]: Jun 24 18:03:26.572 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
```

tor log content

```
tail /var/log/tor/log

Jun 24 18:03:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay

Jun 24 18:03:27.000 [notice] Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control

Jun 24 18:03:27.000 [notice] Opened Control listener connection (ready) on /run/tor/control

Jun 24 18:03:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay

Jun 24 18:03:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay

Jun 24 18:03:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done

Jun 24 18:03:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits

Jun 24 18:03:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits

Jun 24 18:03:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit

Jun 24 18:03:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done
```

Comment: How are you running tor? Using the daemon installed with the APT package? Or do you run tor manually on the command line? If using the daemon, it runs as the 'debian-tor' user, so make sure that user has access to your sock file.

Comment: @Steve Im using the daemon ```sudo systemctl start tor``` and I have changed permissions in the sock file to the following
```
namei -nom /home/agua/sockets/nginx.sock
f: /home/agua/sockets/nginx.sock
 drwxr-xr-x root       root     /
 drwxr-xr-x root       root     home
 drwxr-xr-x agua       agua     agua
 drwxrwxrwx agua       agua     sockets
 srwxrwxrwx debian-tor www-data nginx.sock
```

Comment: To check the tor service status, you should use `systemctl status tor@default` instead of `systemctl status tor`. If you could post the tor log contents, that would also be helpful.

Comment: @Steve I have updated post with ```systemctl status tor@default``` and the tor log content